# How to verify all words in the search result starts with specific letter using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I enter "A" in the search field and hit enter. I got a list of employees. I need to verify all the employees' names in the search result starts with the letter "A".

Comment: Can you provide more information like DOM or site ? Which field you are trying to verify ?

Answer (score 0):

An example where you need just to locate all the employee names found:

```
WebElement[] employees = driver.findElements(By. ...)
for (WebElement employee: employees) {
    if (!employee == null && employee.getText().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase().equals("a") {
        System.out.print(employee + " begins with 'a'")
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(employee + " does not begin with 'a'")
    }
}
```

I don't know the source page. Maybe the employee name can be mined (as well) this way:

```
employee.getAttribute("value")
```